# PHP telegram bot - inline_keyboard русские и английские символы

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Доброго времени суток.
При написании бота столкнулся с такой проблемой.
все нормально отрабатывает до тех пор пока значение `$element` не равно
`"Фитолизин Паста 100г Польша Herba med"` именно эта строка.
Т.е ничего не выводится на экран даже если прописать вручную.
При чем если это же значение будет `"Фитолизин Паста 100г Польша"` без `"Herba med"` то все работает, размер строки тут не причем, размер `$callbackdata` позволяет.

Помогите разобраться пожалуйста:-)

```
$link содержит строку 'view_AptekaAll.php?id=1000'    
$callbackdata="link=".$link;    
$inline_button = array("text"=>$element,"callback_data"=>$callbackdata);                        
$inline_keyboard[] = [$inline_button];    
$keyboard=array("inline_keyboard"=>$inline_keyboard);    
$replyMarkup = json_encode($keyboard);     
sendMessage($chat_id_in, $doctor_icon, $replyMarkup);
```

Comment: а ограничение на длину строку там не стоит?

Comment: проверьте кодировку

Comment: Кодировка UTF-8